# Остановить Timer в fragment при закрытии приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение с `Viewpager`. Когда приложение запущено, в одном из фрагментов специально постоянно идёт таймер.

При закрытии приложения выпадает такая ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                 Process: com.example.administrator.myapp, PID: 6571
                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                 at com.example.administrator.myapp.MyFragment$myTimerTask.run(MyFragment.java:228)
                 at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Могу предположить, что проблема в том, что при закрытии таймер из фрагмента не останавливается.

Для закрытия приложения в MainActivity использую код:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        finish();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Что нужно дописать, чтобы при закрытии приложения таймер в fragment  останавливался или сам фрагмент закрывался?

> Нижеприведённый код вставленный в fragment не подходит, так как: 1)
>   всё равно вылетает ошибка; 2) при пролистывании фрагментов таймер
>   останавливается, а нужно чтобы работал, когда приложение запущено.
>
> ```
> @Override
>         public void onPause() {
>             getActivity().finish();
>             super.onPause();
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно останавливать таймер в методе `onDestroy()` активити
`timer.cancel();`

Comment: Код поместить в Fragment?

Comment: @Михаил, можете попробовать переопределить метод ondestroy у фрагмента и вставить туда cancel()